# Why does the sort command sort differently if there are trailing fields?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

Considering the sort key: a, a01 and a02, if there's no trailing fields, the sort result looks like:

```
$ cat test1
a01
a
a02
$ sort test1
a
a01
a02
$
```

But if there are tailing fields, something goes strange:

```
$ cat test2
a01 7
a 12
a02 42
$ sort test2
a01 7
a02 42
a 12
$
```

Why does the key "a" fall from the top to the bottom of the sort result?

My sort version is "sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page for my version of `sort` says:

```
***  WARNING  *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  
Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

And indeed, if I set `LC_ALL=C` and run `sort` on your second example, I get:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort < tosort 
a 12
a01 7
a02 42
```

Your default locate is probably something other than `C`.