# Unix sort producing wrong output

Tags: python, sorting, unix, hadoop

I'm trying to test mapper and reducer functions for a hadoop streaming job by doing:

```
    cat data.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py
```

But the sorted output from the mapper is not correct.

```
he the  1
i       1
i dog   1
i like  1
i'm     1
i'm rob 1
i'm the 1
i the   1 ### this should be after "i like 1" ###
lazy    1
```

I've had other people test on their machines and they get the correct output with the same exact mapper function and command line execution. So it seems that something is going wrong with my Unix sort.

If this helps:

```
echo $TERM
> vt100
```

Any suggestions for what to try or set differently would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: was your `data.txt` ever created or edited on a Windows machine? Even if not, try `dos2unix data.txt` and then rerun. Good luck.

Comment: The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.

Comment: Your locale collates `'` and `<space>`, so `sort` compares them as equal and uses the next character to break the tie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825196/449541) and it's about locale. In short, you should use

```
cat data.txt | python mapper.py | LC_COLLATE=C sort
```